# YAML syntax sed in Gitlab-CI

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

I've made a mistake in the file below, but I cannot see where my mistake is. I have this command in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` configuration file.

```
-  sed  "s/use_scm_version=True/use_scm_version={'write_to':  '..\/version.txt', 'root':  '..'},\/"setup.py
```

It seems that the ":" are interpreted as a semicolon even if I surround the entire sed between double quotes.

```
(<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 109 column 11
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your double quotes are not at the beginning of the scalar node, they don't have special meaning in YAML and the colon is seen as the normal value indicator (and both the key and value have an embedded double quote).

I recommend you quote the whole scalar:

```
- "sed  s/use_scm_version=True/use_scm_version={'write_to':  '..\/version.txt', 'root':  '..'},\/setup.py"
```

And optionally add `\"` (backslash escaped double quotes) as necessary within there if that doesn't work.